# Why are images duplicated with append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

When a "project" is clicked, I want multiple images to be appended to a container element.
Projects and their image URLs are defined in a JavaScript object.

If I click a project, its images are correctly appended. But if I close the project viewer and click that project again, the images are all duplicated. I think this has something to do with `append()`.

What am I doing wrong?

I made a demonstration below:

```js
$(function() {

  var projects = {

    'project_1': {
      'title': 'EduTravel For Credit',
      'description': 'Innovative travel for credit.',
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/1/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/2/'
      ]
    }

  }

  var projectData = projects["project_1"];

  jQuery('button').on('click', function() {

    $.each(projectData.images, function(item) {
      $('#project-images').append('<span class="image_holder" style="background-image:url(' + projectData.images[item] + ');"></span>')
    });

    $('#project_images').html('');

  });

});
```

```css
.image_holder {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>CLICK ME</button>

<div id="project-images"></div>
```

[View the live website](http://www.darrenbachan.com/)

Comment: press F12 and learn to use what you see there, debugging websites is very easy

Comment: Can you include the relevant javascript/html in your question?

Comment: Share your html/javascript code and you will get help

Comment: It seems that you'd want to clear `#project-images` each time you load a new project. I see `$('#project_images').html('');` in your code, but it has an underscore instead of a hyphen. Also, it comes *after* you append all the images, rather than before.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the problem and added a working demonstration. If you feel my edit is not correct or appropriate, feel free to rollback the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code on your website, it seems that you might be attempting to remove images from the container before appending new images:

```
$('#project_images').html('');
```

However, that selector uses an underscore while the actual element uses a hyphen:

```
<div id="project-images">
```

Also, you are clearing the contents *after* appending images rather than before.
I suggest using jQuery's [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) on the container before appending new images:

```js
$(function() {

  var projects = {

    'project_1': {
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/1/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/2/'
      ]
    },
    'project_2': {
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/3/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/4/'
      ]
    },
    'project_3': {
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/5/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/6/'
      ]
    }

  }

  var projectData = projects["project_1"];

  jQuery('button').on('click', function() {
    
    var id=jQuery(this).data('id'),
        projectData=projects["project_"+id];

    $('#project-images').empty();
    
    $.each(projectData.images, function(item) {
      $('#project-images').append('<span class="image_holder" style="background-image:url(' + projectData.images[item] + ');"></span>')
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.image_holder {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-id="1">LOAD #1</button>
<button data-id="2">LOAD #2</button>
<button data-id="3">LOAD #3</button>

<div id="project-images"></div>
```

An alternate method is to concatenate a string of new images, and then set the HTML of the container without using `append()`:

```js
$(function() {

  var projects = {

    'project_1': {
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/1/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/2/'
      ]
    },
    'project_2': {
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/3/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/4/'
      ]
    },
    'project_3': {
      'images': [
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/5/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/30/abstract/6/'
      ]
    }

  }

  var projectData = projects["project_1"];

  jQuery('button').on('click', function() {
    
    var id=jQuery(this).data('id'),
        projectData=projects["project_"+id],
        html_string='';
    
    $.each(projectData.images, function(item) {
      html_string+='<span class="image_holder" style="background-image:url(' + projectData.images[item] + ');"></span>';
    });
    
    $('#project-images').html(html_string);

  });

});
```

```css
.image_holder {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-id="1">LOAD #1</button>
<button data-id="2">LOAD #2</button>
<button data-id="3">LOAD #3</button>

<div id="project-images"></div>
```

Comment: $('#project-images').empty(''); this worked, thanks. I apologize for not formatting my question properly. I'm new to all of this and I don't really understand what any of what you mentioned means. I'm trying to take javascript tutorials online so one day I could have a better understanding. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask more questions. And keep coding!